Source of H+ in soil?
I am a soil science nerd reading The Nature and Properties of Soil, 14th edition (ISBN-13 978-0132279383).
In discussion of $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$, page 425 contains the statement

Dissociation of the acid can usually be considered negligible when the pH is more than 1 to 2 units lower than the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$.

Why is this so?

You can relate the ratio of concentrations (weak acid vs conjugate weak base) to the difference between $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ and pH:
$$\frac{c(\mathrm{acid})}{c(\mathrm{base})} = 10^{( \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} - \mathrm{pH})}$$
When the difference is more than 1, less than 10% dissociate, when it is more than 2, less than 1% dissociate. Whether you consider this negligible depends on the context, of course.
This behavior is related to how an equilibrium responds to changing concentrations. The equilibrium in question is:
$$\ce{AH(aq) <=> A-(aq) + H+(aq)}$$
where AH is the acid and A- the conjugate base. Raising the H+ concentration results in more acid and less conjugate base. So a lower pH results in more of the acid form, and a higher pH in more of the base form. When the pH is equal to the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$, they are at a 1:1 ratio.

[OP] I am a soil science nerd

Maybe you should add chemistry to your nerdiness. You can't understand soil without a good understanding of fundamental chemistry concepts.

This has become abundantly clear

Aside from a good textbook, what resource would you recommend?

You could take a course at a community college, look into free online courses (MOOCs), or cobble together resources (problem sets, videos) from the internet. I don't know a good textbook for self-study; I am in a course-based learning space.
